# Why could this process have crashed?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an 8AM Access macro that verifies certain SQL tables are up to date. For business logic reasons, the Access file is stored and run on both my local machine and a virtual machine.  It's pretty simple and almost always runs without problems:

1. Windows task scheduler kicks off an Access macro.
2. The macro runs queries on several tables from our SQL server to find the date those tables were last updated.
3. Results are saved to a table in the same Access file.

This morning, the local process ran fine, but the VM process didn't return any records (I'm pretty sure it crashed, but I didn't capture the error message).  Can anyone guess why the process on the virtual machine crashed, but the exact same process on the local didn't crash?

#### Edit

I should add that everything on my local and the virtual run independently of each other.

Comment: Since Access does not have any logging built in, I have always built logging with my own library to write to a text file or a database table.

Comment: Can you run the process on VM manually?

Comment: Yes. When I arrived at work about 30 minutes after it crashed, everything ran fine.  The SQL Server tables hadn't been updated in that time, so I was working with the same data, and all the data looked good.

Comment: Are you trying to run the same Access database in two instances of Windows? Or does the virtual machine have its own copy? Are they writing data to the same data file or to two different files? Last of all, why is this necessary?

Comment: @David, The 2 machines are completely independent of each other and they are saving the data in their own mdbs. I'm migrating some reporting processes from the local to the virtual, so this process will eventually disappear from my local machine entirely.

Comment: I know it's one of those "is it plugged in?" type of questions, but while you think it's operating on different files, have you confirmed that it is, in fact, operating on different files? And what's the purpose of running it in a VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you positive the VM process started?  at 8:00 AM?

If the virtual machine clock was running slow, perhaps the VM thought it was before 8:00 AM when you checked.

Comment: According to the task scheduler log, yes, it did start at 8am and it was force closed 10 minutes later because it was still open.  I'm inferring from this that the Access query threw an error which halted the entire thing until the task scheduler closed it.